# Concurrent Modification Exception with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.concurrent, concurrentmodification

I have a problem with `ConcurrentModificationException`.

I have an `ArrayList` of `Complex` class that I defined.  I added two `Complex`es, and try to do a *for each* loop but I get the `ConcurrentModificationException`. However, when I remove that line, I get no error.  I need those initial points `(1,0)`, `(-1,0)` to calculate points that I will need later.

```
        for (Iterator<Complex> num = dots.iterator(); num.hasNext();) {
            // ConcurrentModificationException
            Complex aComplex = num.next();
            // clone it and clear
            temp.add(new Complex(aComplex));
            dots.clear();
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `dots.clear()` and `temp.clear()` be outside of the corresponding for's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection while iterating on it. If you would move dots.clear(); and temp.clear() outside iterations; it will get resolved. If needed you can create a flag whenever these collections need to be cleared; and after iteration is over you can clear them.

Answer (score 0):

Most iterators implementations don't allow the underlying structure to be modified unless it's with the defined semantics on the iterator itself (the `remove` method).

So, in all the sections of the code where you are clearing the structure *while* iterating over it, you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.